# Why this render function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been playing with backbone and trying to learn it. I'm stuck at this point for a while. Not able to figure out what's wrong with following code?

```
  render: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    // render each subview, appending to our root element
    _.each(this._views, function(sub_view) {
      this.$el.append(sub_view.render().el); // Error on this line
   });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have got context issue. `this` you are refering to doesn't contain the `$el` you are looking for. You can fix this by declaring a `self` variable that points to appropriate `this`. Following code should work for you.

```
render: function() {
    var self = this; //Added this line to declare variable (self) that point to 'this' 
    this.$el.empty();
    _.each(this._views, function(sub_view) {
      self.$el.append(sub_view.render().el); //Used 'self' here instead 'this' 
});
```

**Side Note:** As you are leaning backbone also you should know about a very commong JavaScript problem with document reflow. You are render a view for every single model in the collection. It can lead to performance issues and especially on old computers and mobile devices. You can optimise your code by rendering everything in `container` and appending it once, rather than updating DOM each time. Here is an example:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.empty();
  var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
  _.each(this._views, function(sub_view) {
    container.appendChild(sub_view.render().el)
  });
  this.$el.append(container);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works great! Thanks a lot and also I'll keep in mind document flow issue. Very useful info indeed!